# How to Avoid Prompts When Installing Ubuntu-Drivers for Nvidia GeForce GPU

Tags: drivers, keyboard-layout, nvidia-geforce, ubuntu-drivers

Running Ubuntu Focal Fossa on a laptop with Nvidia GeForce GPU. Using the following script as part of some automated set up, particularly for my NVIDIA GPUs and cuDNN set up. (Right now it is happening on my laptop, but potentially it can happen inside a docker container)

```
# Running as root
apt-get --assume-yes --no-install-recommends install ubuntu-drivers-common wget
ubuntu-drivers install
```

The last command is asking me for prompt regarding my keyboard layout, like this.
[image]

Clearly this would not work as part of a container set up. But I cannot find any option to pre-empt this prompt from the `ubuntu-drivers` manual either. I do use US International layout. Earlier it was also asking for a timezone prompt, which I managed to preempt by setting the timezone, but any help regarding the keyboard prompt will be appreciated.

Comment: Will `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` do what you want?

Comment: The manual says ```autoinstall``` is slated to be deprecated and recommends ```install``` instead. I tried it nonetheless, from what I see it does the same job and asks for the same prompt.